# How to answer "Is applicant eligible for Non-ECR category?"

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, ecr

I am applying for a passport for my mother. She has completed the 10th grade and she is about 58 years old.

The following question has been presented:

> Is applicant eligible for Non-ECR category?

Is the correct answer for her 'Yes' or 'No'?

If  'Yes', what documents are required to prove this?

Comment: ECR stands for [Emigration Check Required](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_passport#Emigration_check), which applies specifically to Indian passports. I don't know anything more about it than what the acronym means. I've tagged the question appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

The page cited by @GregHewgill indicates that persons over the age of 50 qualify for Emigration Check Not Required (Non-ECR). [This](http://mea.gov.in/images/pdf/emigration_and_you_new.pdf) PDF from the Indian Ministry of External Affairs confirms the over 50 category.

Presumably, evidence of her age should be sufficient, but you or she should contact the passport agency to confirm. Alternately, she can apply and wait and see if the passport agency requests further evidence of her age, and then proceed from there.

Comment: Why on earth do their computers not automatically know that an applicant above 50 should automatically be qualified instead of asking the applicant if they do? Surely they have the dob on record